# Add Managed Module IIS error when adding managed module on sharepoint server 2019 application

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I have hosted My Site application on IIS using Sharepoint Server 2019. When I try to add a managed module, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
Add Managed Module
---------------------------
There was an error while performing this operation.
Details: 

Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8f79ccb0\64f5947a\c3uhqjaq.cmdline".
```

The application is a standard One Drive for Business application. My .Net version installed is 4.8.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $release = Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -Name Release
PS C:\Users\Administrator> switch ($release) {
>>     { $_ -ge 533320 } { $version = '4.8.1 or later'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 528040 } { $version = '4.8'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 461808 } { $version = '4.7.2'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 461308 } { $version = '4.7.1'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 460798 } { $version = '4.7'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 394802 } { $version = '4.6.2'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 394254 } { $version = '4.6.1'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 393295 } { $version = '4.6'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 379893 } { $version = '4.5.2'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 378675 } { $version = '4.5.1'; break }
>>     { $_ -ge 378389 } { $version = '4.5'; break }
>>     default { $version = $null; break }
>> }
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
PS C:\Users\Administrator> if ($version) {
>>     Write-Host -Object ".NET Framework Version: $version"
>> } else {
>>     Write-Host -Object '.NET Framework Version 4.5 or later is not detected.'
>> }
.NET Framework Version: 4.8
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Any guidelines on how to fix this error would be appreciated.